# NoClassDefFoundError ShadowSQLiteConnection Error When Testing Service With Database Helper

Tags: android, sqlite, unit-testing, android-service, robolectric

I am trying to test a service with Robolectric.  It so happens the service creates a DB connection checks something and then closes.  The problem is I get a Robo error that it can't find the class.

```
Could not initialize class org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSQLiteConnection

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSQLiteConnection
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
at org.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler.createShadowFor(ShadowWrangler.java:354)
at org.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler.initializing(ShadowWrangler.java:81)
at org.robolectric.bytecode.RobolectricInternals.initializing(RobolectricInternals.java:72)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.$$robo$init(SQLiteConnection.java)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:162)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:190)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185) ...
```

My code that calls this is:

```
@Config(manifest = "../App/AndroidManifest.xml",shadows = { MyShadowSystemClock.class})
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class DataServiceTest {

    MyActivity activity;
    Context context;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        ShadowLog.stream = System.out;
    }

    @Test
    public void testServiceActionReference() throws InterruptedException {
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(Robolectric.application, DataService.class);
        startIntent.setAction("GET_DATA");
        DataService service = new DataService();
        service.onCreate();
        service.onStartCommand(startIntent, 0, 42);
        service.onHandleIntent(startIntent);
           assertEquals(DataService.class.getCanonicalName(),startIntent.getComponent().getClassName());
        service.stopService(startIntent);
        service.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

What am I missing so that I can prevent these errors?

Also see this on the sys out when running ant:

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot extractAndLoad SQLite
library into C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Temp\robolectric-libs\sqlite4java.d
ll

Answer (score -1):

Are you using a really old version? This seems to be the problem.

Comment: I'm not but maybe robo is?